# MvvmCross: PictureChooser Plugin - Preview screen Button Text

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

Is there a way to change the text in iOS and Android for the two buttons which showing up inside the Picture Preview screen after you take a photo using MvvmCross PictureChooser plugin?

I have searched on it but I can't seam to find anything.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way provided by MvvmCross to do this.

The source code to the picture chooser is in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/v3.1/Plugins/Cirrious/PictureChooser

On Droid, this uses the standard ActionGetContent intent - https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Plugins/Cirrious/PictureChooser/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.PictureChooser.Droid/MvxPictureChooserTask.cs#L37

On iOS, this uses the standard UIImagePickerController - https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Plugins/Cirrious/PictureChooser/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.PictureChooser.Touch/MvxImagePickerTask.cs

So to customise these, you'll need to replace this code or to look to see if there are any "standard" ways on each platform.